# HTML5 Date validation using PHP, must be 24hours or more

Tags: php, html

I cant get past this point. I am new to PHP and need to have a user select the date using HTML5 date input, then PHP will check that it is not today or before today. I've tried a bunch of things, can anyone help out. Also this is my first post ever.

**PHP**

```
if (empty($_POST["pickupDate"])) {
$pickupDateErr = "Pickup Date is required";
    } elseif (strtotime($pickupDate) < date('Y-m-d')){
        echo date('Y-m-d');
    $pickupDateErr = "Date must be tomorrow or later";
```

**HTML5**

```
<p>Preferred Date: <input type="date" name="pickupDate" value="<?php echo $pickupDate;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $pickupDateErr;?></span></p>
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the posted date to a date ( at least I did and it worked )

```
    $pickupDateErr = "No errors";

    if ( empty( $_POST["pickupDate"] ) ) {

        $pickupDateErr = "Pickup Date is required";

    /* Cast the POSTed value as a date after converting using strtotime */
    } elseif( date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST["pickupDate"] ) ) <= date('Y-m-d') ){

        echo date('Y-m-d');
        $pickupDateErr = "Date must be tomorrow or later";

    }
    echo $pickupDateErr;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Date](http://php.net/date) is returning a human-readable date, while [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) is returning a unix-timestamp (a bunch of seconds). Quite logically, you cannot simply compare two completely different type of values by simply using the greater or lesser operators.

Comparing dates by converting time to unix-time is getting really old now, seriously! Here is one solution with PHP 5.3's [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), which actually allows comparison of dates with the use of equality operatros:

```
// DateTime throws an error if you haven't set a timezone, change it to yours
$pickupDate = new DateTime($_POST["pickupDate"], new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));
$today = new DateTime('today', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia')); // 'today', 'now', you can use anything you want

if (empty($_POST["pickupDate"])) {
    $pickupDateErr = "Pickup Date is required";
} elseif ($pickupDate <= $today) { // <, >, =  No problem
    echo $today->format('Y-m-d'); // Easy formatting
    $pickupDateErr = "Date must be tomorrow or later";
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will use this in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST["pickupDate"])) {
$pickupDateErr = "Pickup Date is required";
    } elseif (strtotime($pickupDate) < time() - 60 * 60 * 24){
        echo date('Y-m-d');
    $pickupDateErr = "Date must be tomorrow or later";
```